# What is the package that declares shortcuts like \RR for \mathbb{RR}?

Tags: math-mode, packages

I feel like there's a standard LaTeX package that has all these shortcuts declared but I can't remember what it's called and searching doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Might not be a package at all, just people defining their own macros with `\newcommand`.

Comment: I think the answer is simply that there is no such package: https://www.ctan.org/topic/maths

Comment: @Ruben: How can I use that page to determine whether or not something is in a package?  For instance, if I wanted to know that the shortcut \dfrac comes from amsmath, how could I do that?

Comment: I think I've used that package. Will see if I can find it.

Comment: The link I posted is just a list of all math related packages on ctan, not to a package page. Regarding your question there is in fact a solution: Try `texdef -t latex dfrac` (of course, the `texdef` package has to be installed, but it is by default in any of the major distros, I think.)

Comment: The package I had used was [skmath](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/skmath/skmath.pdf) but apparently uses \R etc for the commands. From the documentation: "This package intends to provide helpful (re-)definitions of commands
related to typesetting mathematics, and specifically typesetting them in
a more intuitive, less verbose and more beautiful way."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just search your local tree, eg

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```

Then:

```
grep '\\RR[^a-Z]' */*.sty
```

produces

```
akktex/akkmathset.sty:\newcommand   \RR                 {{\mathbb R}}
akktex/akkmathset.sty:\newcommand   \RRm                {\RR^m}
akktex/akkmathset.sty:\newcommand   \RRn                {\RR^n}
akktex/akkmathset.sty:\newcommand   \sqsetrr            {\sqset \RR}
cryptocode/cryptocode.sty:        \providecommand\RR{\mathbb{R}}
xyling/xyling.sty:\let\RR\DR
```

which suggests `akkmathset` and `cryptocode` packages both define `\RR` the way you suggest.

Comment: Thanks.  What if the package isn't installed on my system -- is there some way to search a repository in the same way?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury sure you can search ctan via google, but to be honest just writing the commands would be easier:-)

Comment: I usually write the commands out, but retyping several dozen of them (between \mathbb, \mathscr, \mathcal, and \mathfrak) in every single document I write is getting increasingly annoying.  I could make my own file, of course, but then I'd have to make sure that file was on all the various computers I use.